# Is $\sum_{c \notin \mathbb Z_q}\psi(c)-\sum_{c \notin \mathbb Z_q}\psi(c^n)$ an integer?

Tags: finite-fields, characters, finite-rings

Let $n$ be a positive integer. Let $p$ be an odd prime and $q=p^k$. Let $c \in \mathbb Z_q$. Consider the additive character $\psi:\mathbb Z_q \rightarrow \mathbb C^{\times}$ that is defined as $\psi(m)=e^{2\pi im/p^k}$. Is the following always an integer?
$$\sum_{c \notin \mathbb Z^{\times}_q}\psi(c)-\sum_{c \notin \mathbb Z^{\times}_q}\psi(c^n)$$
where $\mathbb Z^{\times}_q$ is the multiplicative group of $\mathbb Z_q$

Comment: What do you sum over? $c\notin\mathbb Z_q$ - where is $c$?

Comment: I fixed the question. Sorry about that...

Comment: If you take it over $c\in\mathbb Z_q^\times$ (in place of $c\notin \mathbb Z_p^\times$) then it's rational by say Galois theory and integer since it's an algebraic integer. If you sum over $c\in\mathbb Z_q$ then it's clearly an integer (0 unless $p^k$ divides $n$). So it is always integer.

Comment: thank you. But I did not clearly understand why it is integer if I take the sum over $\mathbb Z_q^{\times}$

Answer (score 0):

Since $\psi$'s domain is precisely $\Bbb Z_q$, both sums are empty sums, conventionally taken to be $0$. Thus, you have have $0-0=0$, an integer.

Comment: I fixed the question. It is changed now... Sorry about the syntax..